# Maximizing linear objective subject to quadratic equality constraint

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, qclp

I've been trying to get through some practice questions on the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) theorem but I can't seem to answer the following.

---

> Given $f, g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) := x_1 + x_2$ and $g(x) := x_1^2+3x_1x_2+3x_2^2-3$, respectively, $$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{maximize}} & f(x)\\ \text{subject to} & g(x) = 0\end{array}$$

---

My attempt:

$$\nabla f(x)=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ $$\nabla g(x)=\begin{pmatrix}
2x_1+3x_2\\
3x_1+6x_2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ and by complementary slackness $\lambda[x_1^2+3x_1x_2+3x_2^2-3]=0$ and $\lambda\geq0$

By first order conditions, I get $\lambda[2x_1+3x_2]=1$ and $\lambda[3x_1+6x_2]=1$

I checked WolframAlpha and the answer should be (3,-1) but I can't seem to figure out the right steps to solve this optimization.

Comment: What is your question? There is no $h$ given. There is no slack with an equality constraint.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm pretty much stuck and can't solve this optimization. Also, I don't know why but I'm getting confused on when to use the complementary slack constraint. I looked it up and most solutions would make use of the constraint.

Comment: This is Lagrange multipliers, there is no inequality constraint. You can solve the equations you got from the first order conditions to get a relationship between $x_1, x_2$. Then use this relationship with $g(x) = 0$ to obtain solutions and figure out which one gives the lower value of $f$.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Note that $g'(x)$ is an invertible matrix times $x$. You can solve explicitly for $x$ in terms of $\lambda$.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1832510/339790).

Comment: I honestly don't follow. I tried equating  just to get an expression and plug it back into the constraint, but I don't think I'm doing it right as I'm not getting the right values.

Comment: IMHO, this is easier if you write in matrix form.

Comment: Why don't you read my second comment carefully and think about it a little.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

You were so close.
Solving the linear system
$\lambda[2x_1+3x_2]=1,\lambda[3x_1+6x_2]=1$ yields
$x_1=1/ \lambda, x_2=-1/(3\lambda)$ and plug this into the KKT condition
yields
$$
\lambda \left( 3\cdot \frac{1}{9\lambda^2}-3 \right)= 0
$$
Because $\lambda$ must be positive, we end up with $\lambda=+1/3$
from which you will deduce that $(3,-1)$ is the solution you are searching.